# How to find longest and shortest length of a value for a field in mongoDb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, mongoid

The data type of the field is String. I would like to find the length of the longest and shortest value for a field in mongoDB.

I have totally 500000 documents in my collection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a mongo shell script. Note that it will perform a full table scan.

```
    function findMinMax() {
        var max = 0;
        var min = db.collection.findOne().fieldName.length;

        db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
            var currentLength = doc.fieldName.length; 
            if (currentLength > max) {
               max = currentLength;
            }
            if (currentLength < min) {
               min = currentLength;
            }
        });

         print(max);
         print(min);
    }

   use <databaseName>
   findMinMax();
```

You can save the function in a file say c:\minMax.js and run the file as,

```
c:\mongodb\bin> mongo dbName < c:\minMax.js
```

Note: you may need to supply the necessary hostname, user name, password to connect to your database.

```
c:\mongodb\bin> mongo --host hostName --port portNumber -u userName -p password dbName < c:\minMax.js
```

Comment: How to run this as a mongo shell script?

Comment: So when I save the function as minMax.js, should I replace  db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {  with db.<MyCollectionName>.find().forEach(function(doc)?
Should I also give my database name here  use <databaseName>?

Comment: I extends this answer and share it onto github cf. https://github.com/boly38/mongo-scripts

Answer (score 12):

In modern releases MongoDB has the [`$strLenBytes`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenBytes/) or [`$strLenCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/) aggregation operators than allow you to simply do:

```ruby
Class.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group" => {
    "_id" => nil,
    "max" => { "$max" => { "$strLenCP" => "$a" } },
    "min" => { "$min" => { "$strLenCP" => "$a" } }
  }}
])
```

Where `"a"` is the string property in your document you want to get the min and max length from.

---

To output the minimum and maximum length, the best approach available is to use [mapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/) with a few tricks to just keep the values.

First you define a mapper function which is just really going to output a single item from your collection to reduce the load:

```ruby
map = Q%{
    function () {

      if ( this.a.length < store[0] )
        store[0] = this.a.length;

      if ( this.a.length > store[1] )
        store[1] = this.a.length;

      if ( count == 0 )
        emit( null, 0 );

      count++;

    }
}
```

Since this is working mostly with a globally scoped variable keeping the min and max lengths you just want to substitute this in a `finalize` function on the single document emitted. There is no reduce stage, but define a "blank" function for this even though it is not called:

```ruby
reduce = Q%{ function() {} }

finalize = Q%{
    function(key,value) {
        return {
            min: store[0],
            max: store[1]
        };
    }
}
```

Then call the mapReduce operation:

```ruby
Class.map_reduce(map,reduce).out(inline: 1).finalize(finalize).scope(store: [], count: 0)
```

So all the work is done on the server and not by iterating results sent to the client application. On a small set like this:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("543e8ee7ddd272814f919472"), "a" : "this" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("543e8eedddd272814f919473"), "a" : "something" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("543e8ef6ddd272814f919474"), "a" : "other" }
```

You get a result like this (shell output, but much the same for the driver ):

```js
{
    "results" : [
            {
                    "_id" : null,
                    "value" : {
                            "min" : 4,
                            "max" : 9
                    }
            }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 1,
    "counts" : {
            "input" : 3,
            "emit" : 1,
            "reduce" : 0,
            "output" : 1
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

So mapReduce allows the JavaScript processing on the server to do this fairly quickly, reducing your network traffic. There is no other native way at present for MongoDB to return a string length right now, so the JavaScript processing is necessary on the server.

Comment: @muistooshort Why emit 500000 documents is more the point. The OP just wants the min and max values. The global is `JavaScript` declared and is cast as such. And only accessible to the mapReduce functions. Clear enough?

Comment: @muistooshort MongoDB does not have any other operator to return the length of a string, so you need JavaScript and mapReduce is the only way to "return" a result. It might be better if there was something native, but this is still a "global" comparison of one document value against another, again where mapReduce is the only thing that is offered to provide this. Banging 500,000 documents at a reducer to do the work that can be done in the mapper would be a hack and unnecessary, not to mention more work. There's no inner strings in the quoted JavaScript so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Or maybe for new mongos you should use ":" istead of "=>" and "null" istead of "nil". Plus db.collections...

Comment: @AntonLosev It's "Ruby" that uses `=>` and `nil` as referenced by the [`mongoid`](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/) tag on the question. Hence also the `Q%` thing for the mapreduce example executing JavaScript on the server from the "Ruby" code. So that's what you missed.

Comment: got it, it was easy to miss)

Answer (score 8):

For getting the longest value for a field

```
db.entities.aggregate([{ $match:{ condition   }  },{
  $addFields: {
    "length": { $strLenCP: "$feildName" }
  }},
{ "$sort": { "length": -1 } },
{$limit:1}
])
```

Change the { "$sort": { "length": -1 } } to { "$sort": { "length": 1 } } for the shortest value for a field

Answer (score 1):

While utilizing the aggregation framework is definitely the preferred way to go, the below answer will not work for fields that might contain null values.

To overcome this we need to use the `$ifNull` operator (replace `fieldName` with the field you wish to query):

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            fieldNameLength: {
                $strLenCP: { $ifNull: ["$fieldName", ""] }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            maxLength: { $max: "$fieldNameLength" }
        }
    }
])
```